# What creature types can be found in Curse of Strahd?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, published-adventures, ranger, curse-of-strahd

I'm making a Ranger (revised) in Curse of Strahd and thinking of what Favored Enemy to pick. Undead seems like the obvious one since the adventure is about a Vampire, but maybe there aren't that many undead besides him.

What can someone who has played/read it tell me about enemy type distribution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Spoilers below!

(I have only *played* the adventure, but did not read it, so I might have missed quite a few encounters, distorting my impressions)

The enemy types are quite evenly distributed:

> 1. **Humanoids** mostly, as lycantropes also fall into this category
>  2. **Undeads** close second
>  3. **Beasts** mostly wolves and bat swarms
>  4. **Fiends** far behind the others
>  5. **Fey** even fewer
> In Strahd's castle Humanoids fall to the third place.

Answer (score 3):

## Humanoids, probably

Since you're playing Revised Ranger, I'd take advantage of their ability to choose all humanoids as your favored enemy. All humanoids is such a broad category that it's typically the best one unless you know you're going to be fighting something else way more often.

That being said, undead is also a very strong choice for Curse of Strahd and it probably provides more "flavour" than having humanoids as your favored enemy. If you're only concerned about utility/strength with this ability, humanoids is probably your best bet, because humanoids covers such a huge blanket. Undead is a close second though.

Greater Favored Enemy will be a much less useful trait in this particular campaign however--I think the only choice that really has much of a presence is Fiends, and they're pretty sparse (I could be wrong about that though).